# JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW cannot work with JCombobox

Tags: java, swing

I had screen below:
[image]

```
public BillSummaryScreen() {
   ..........
   ShortcutKeyUtils.createShortcutKey(this, KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, "enterShortcut", new EnterAction());

}

public static void createShortcutKey(JComponent panel, int keyEventCode, String actionShortcutName, AbstractAction action){
        InputMap inputMap =  panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyEventCode, 0), actionShortcutName);
        ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap();
        actionMap.put(actionShortcutName, action);
    }

private class EnterAction extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("EnterAction");
        }

    }
```

I want to press "ENTER" key so the search button is clicked. **But when i focus into one combobox(by mouse) and i pressed ENTER, the action did not work**

Comment: The [Enter] is likely been consumed by the combobox

Comment: @MadProgrammer
Sure, but how can we prevent this ? because when i focus on combobox after i finished selection, the [Enter] is still conusmed by the combobox.

Comment: @zerone, can you please show us the code of `EnterAction` Action ?

Comment: updated EnterAction, it's nothing, i'm testing Sage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are only interested in the ENTER binding, you might consider defining the search button as the rootpane's default button: this will pass the enter on the comboBox automatically to the button's action.

```
JButton searchButton = new JButton(searchAction);
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(searchButton);
```

While possible to pass-on arbitrary bindings, that's a bit difficult, both from the usibility perspective (do you really want *both* action to happen, that is the one bound to the component *and* the one in your window binding?) as from the technical perspective. For solving the latter, you basically need a custom component that tricks the binding mechanism into believing that it isn't interested in the keyStroke, f.i. as done in the MultiplexingTextField below.

Doing so for a JComboBox has its own stumbling blocks: you would have to implement a custom comboBoxEditor which uses such a custom textField. As the editor is controlled by the LAF (and looks different for nearly each one), you would need a custom editor per LAF (check the sources and c&p :-).

```
/**
 * A JTextField that allows you to specify an array of KeyStrokes that
 * will have their bindings processed regardless of whether or
 * not they are registered on the JTextField itself. 
 */
public static class MultiplexingTextField extends JTextField {
    private KeyStroke[] strokes;
    private List<KeyStroke> keys;
    MultiplexingTextField(int cols, KeyStroke... strokes) {
        super(cols);
        this.keys = Arrays.asList(strokes);
    }

   @Override
    protected boolean processKeyBinding(KeyStroke ks, KeyEvent e,
                                        int condition, boolean pressed) {
        boolean processed = super.processKeyBinding(ks, e, condition,
                                                    pressed);

        if (processed && condition != JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW
                && keys.contains(ks)) {
            // Returning false will allow further processing
            // of the bindings, eg our parent Containers will get a
            // crack at them.
            return false;
        }
        return processed;
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 but don't understand ..., maybe tomorow will be better day :-)